# Delete function works on localhost but not on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am working on a site and ran across a problem where clicking on my 'delete' link brings up an error page. Works fine on localhost - can't figure out why this would be different in the Heroku site.

Does anyone have any idea how this could be?

My 'Pictures' controller:

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @pictures = Picture.all
  end

  def new
    @pictures = Picture.all
    @picture = Picture.new 
  end

  def create
    @picture = Picture.new(picture_params)

    if @picture.save
      redirect_to new_picture_path, notice: "You just uploaded a picture!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    Picture.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to new_picture_path, notice: "You just deleted a picture!"
  end

...
end
```

My picture/new view:

```
<h1>Upload a new picture</h1>
<br>
<div class="well">
<%= form_for @picture, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
 <%= f.file_field :attachment %>
 <%= f.submit "Upload", class: "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

```
 <h1>Edit existing pictures </h1>

 <% @pictures.each do |picture| %>
    <%= image_tag picture.attachment_url(:thumb) %>
    <%= link_to "Delete", picture_path(picture), method: :delete if user_signed_in? %>
 <% end %>
```

Here are the heroku logs from when I try to delete a picture (starting with navigating to new picture page (new and edit functions in same view):

2015-11-15T16:13:49.189857+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/pictures/new" host=designstatements.herokuapp.com request_id=ccb67000-b99f-4579-a664-097247d97414 fwd="73.238.59.224" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=46ms status=200 bytes=9770

2015-11-15T16:13:49.396294+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/pictures/animate.min.css" host=designstatements.herokuapp.com request_id=fb87e1bd-b5cc-4f9f-9934-6c4076beff41 fwd="73.238.59.224" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=1829

2015-11-15T16:13:49.478789+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/pictures/js/bootstrap.min.js" host=designstatements.herokuapp.com request_id=2b36f60f-0e9a-498f-b210-74350c910540 fwd="73.238.59.224" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=404 bytes=1829

2015-11-15T16:13:53.652050+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/pictures/40" host=designstatements.herokuapp.com request_id=5dbb3c14-fab5-4525-a682-2d037b78dd4a fwd="73.238.59.224" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=10ms status=500 bytes=1754

Comment: could you post logs which occurs during deletion.

Comment: Can you update the question with the error?

Comment: There is no specific error available, only a page that says, "we're sorry but something went wrong."

Comment: Ok @Nithin just edited the question :)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, your assets could not be found (your log states a 404 error for `/pictures/js/bootstrap.min.js`.

Rails uses `jquery-ujs`, a Javascript library, to simulate `DELETE` request, since browsers can only do `GET` and `POST`. `jquery-ujs` turns normal links where you have set `method: :delete` into `POST` requests which have the parameter `_method` set to `delete`. This tells Rails to treat this request as a `DELETE`-request.

Now, if your assets can't be loaded, neither will `jquery-ujs` be loaded. With `jquery-ujs` missing, your links can not be modified and the browser sends a GET-request instead of a fake `DELETE` request.

To fix this, try setting

```
 config.assets.compile = false
```

in your `config/environments/production.rb`. This makes Heroku serve your assets. Maybe you have to change other settings as well (especially your asset path). But as soon as your JS and CSS files are loaded, the `DELETE` links should work.

Comment: hm, that didn't seem to work...looks like assets are being loaded - pictures appear successfully, the only issue is deleting...